# Will stat timeout if file system is not responding?

Tags: c++, nfs

From the stat [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html) , I don't see anything about timeout values.   What happens if you stat a file, but the filesystem is not responsive?   The reason I'm asking is because the file will be on an NFS file system, and so I'm wondering, if the NFS isn't responding, will stat ever return?  Or will it just hang?

Comment: Relevant? https://serverfault.com/questions/889860/how-to-configure-reasonable-timeout-for-nfs

Comment: Moar relevant? https://serverfault.com/questions/9499/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-hard-versus-soft-mounts-in-unix

Comment: NFS has timeouts.